# How to convert redux with immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I want to try to practice how to use `immutable.js`
But I don't know how to edit my reducer to immutable way. (I try to find some code on github,but they are basic)
And my component also has error.
So I want to ask for help to guild me how to refactor my reducer?

Here is my original reducer.js

**original reducer.js**

```
import * as TYPE from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const INIT_STATE = {
  box: [
    { 'id': 1,
      'axisX': 10,
      'axisY': 10,
      'width': 200,
      'height': 200,
    },
    { 'id': 2,
      'axisX': 20,
      'axisY': 300,
      'width': 200,
      'height': 200,
    }
    ]
};


export default function editZone(state = INIT_STATE, action) {
  let newState = null;
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPE.UPDATE_POSITION:
      newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.box = newState.box.map(box => {
        if (box.id === action.payload.id) {
          box.axisX = action.payload.x;
          box.axisY = action.payload.y;
        }
        return box;
      });
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And I edit it to use `immutable.js`, I just add wrap `INIT_STATE` with `fromJS()`

**immutable reducer.js **

```
import {List, Map, fromJS} from 'immutable'; 

const INIT_STATE = fromJS({
      box: [
        { 'id': 1,
          'axisX': 10,
          'axisY': 10,
          'width': 200,
          'height': 200,
        },
        { 'id': 2,
          'axisX': 20,
          'axisY': 300,
          'width': 200,
          'height': 200,
        }
        ]
    });
```

And I face an error :  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
I try to console output `this.props.editZone`
It shows `Map {size: 2, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}`
How can I fix this??

**boxComponent.js**

```
const boxes = this.props.editZone.box;
const playgroundObjetcs = boxes.map(box => { 
    return (...)
});
```

Comment: first use state.get('box') inside reducer to get the box property of state then you can use map on that array.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Immutable.js in my code.

Hope this might help you.

**reducer**

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import actionConsts from 'constants/actions';

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
    isUserLoggedIn: false
});

const user = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionConsts.get('RECEIVE_INIT_DATA'):
            return state.merge(Immutable.fromJS(action.payload.user));
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default user;
```

**Container**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Base from 'components/base';
import 'styles/app.sass';
import { fetchAppBaseData } from 'actions/init';
import { clearErrorAction } from 'actions/error';

class BaseContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Base {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}

BaseContainer.propTypes = {
    skin: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    sim: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    fetchAppBase: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    clearError: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
BaseContainer.defaultProps = {
    skin: {},
    user: {},
    sim: {}
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ ...(state.toJS()) });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchAppBase() {
        dispatch(fetchAppBaseData());
    },

    clearError() {
        dispatch(clearErrorAction());
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseContainer);
```

Comment: How is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference the object property with dot notation because it's an Immutablejs Map (you created the Map in your reducer when you passed your state object in to the fromJS Immutablejs function) to use the function map on that Map you need to use the Immutablejs api to return a new box rather than a reference to the old box.

First use the getIn function which will return a new box rather than a reference to the old box.

Depending on how you have passed your state through the props I can't give you a definitive answer, I am confused where editZone property is coming from as I cannot see it in your initial state only as a function name, are you slicing your state and creating properties from the function names? But anyway you can try something along the lines of

Change:

const boxes = this.props.editZone.box; const playgroundObjetcs = boxes.map(box => { return (...) });

To:

const playgroundObjects = this.props.getIn(['editZone', 'box']).map(box => { return (...) });

Alternatively try:

const boxes = this.props.editZone.box.toJS()
playgroundObjetcs = boxes.map(box => { return (...) });

And hopefully this will make sense now as to what's going on.